# LUN doesn't mount after reboot

Tags: lvm, iscsi, lun

After changing the size of a LUN (grow) on a RHEL 6 System, the LUN/LV (which is part of a Volume Group) does not mount after a reboot anymore. 
I have to execute

`vgchange -a y`

And after that i can mount the LUN normally. Is that normal? Do i need to change something in fstab?

Comment: Please include some more details. The contents of `/etc/fstab` and the output from `pvdisplay`, `lvdisplay` and `vgdisplay` might help. Also, what steps did you take to "tell" the OS about the larger LUN?